# Whenever I try to run my project in codelite, any changes I've made seem to be ignored

Tags: c++, codelite

An example of my situation would be when I add a cout in main and when I build and run the program that cout is never displayed (it's the second line of code so I don't believe the issue has anything to do with the code).

I should also mention that I didn't make this project, a group member did. So I had to create a workspace and add the existing project file that way. Other than the issue I've specified, everything else works like a charm.

Some of the things I've tried include building, rebuilding, stopping and resuming the build, closing and reopening the workspace, closing and reopening the program, making a new workspace, rebuilding the project, reloading the workspace, rebuilding the workspace, and cleaning the workspace. None of these worked. I have no idea what else to do.

There are a lot of classes and header files, so it'd take me awhile to add all of them in here but for now I'll give you main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Charge.h"
#include "Grid.h"
#include "Property.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the world of Monopoly\n";
    cout << endl << "I can work!"; # This is the cout that I added and was ignored.

    //Get the number of players
    int numberOfPlayer;
    setNumberOfPlayer(numberOfPlayer);

    //Get the name of each player
    Player *players = new Player[numberOfPlayer];
    setNameOfPlayer(players, numberOfPlayer);

    //Initialize the map
    cout << "Loading...";
    //Current map size is 10 grids
    int mapSize = 10;
    Grid *grids[mapSize];
    initializeGrids(grids, mapSize);

    //progress is used to record a player's position and whether the player is bankrupt
    Progress *progress = new Progress[numberOfPlayer];
    initializeProgress(progress, numberOfPlayer);
    cout << "Complete\n\n";

    //Start a round. Iteration will continue if the game is not over.
    //Game is over when only one player is not bankrupt
    int round = 0;
    bool gameOver = false;
    while (!gameOver) {
        gameOver = roundStart(round, players, numberOfPlayer, grids, mapSize, progress);
        round++;
    }

    //Print out the winner
    printWinner(players, numberOfPlayer, progress);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you positive your code changes are built? If you put in an invalid code, do you see a build error? If it is building, then you probably start the wrong executable. I don't use codelite myself, but you should check which executable it runs. It might run the old one, but build the new one in a different location or a different name.

Comment: I took the ; out of the cout I added and I just tried building it, no errors.

Comment: That means the IDE is using different files for building the code. Look at the settings which files it uses. You are just modifying a copy of the actual files.

Comment: The IDE seems to be using a debug folder to run the program.

Comment: It doesn't matter which folder it uses to run the program, it's important to know which files it uses for compiling/linking.

Comment: I've never really had to do this so I don't know much about what I'm doing, but I went to settings -> build settings and now I see compiler options and linker options, however, I don't see anything about what files it is trying to use inside either of these options.

Comment: Codelite seems to use CMake for compiling/linking/etc. its projects. See https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php for information about it.

Answer (score -1):

statement : ***cout << endl << "I can work!";*** works good, it output your string. Ok,  you can try ***cout<< " \n I can work!";***.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question at all.

Comment: Helping to improve the code is a good idea, but that's better done as a comment and not as 'Answer'.

Answer (score -1):

The order problem , try

```
cout << "I can work!" << endl;
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the IDE seems to be trying to build a completely different project from the one I've edited.